# Using Gradle Dependency inside of Custom Plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy

I am trying to write a custom Gradle Plugin that invokes the flyway migration using their API:

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/

This is a minimal example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories.jcenter()
    dependencies.classpath "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.1.2"
}

apply plugin: DatabaseHandlerPlugin

class DatabaseHandlerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task("databaseHandler").doLast {
            org.flywaydb.Flyway f = new Flyway(); // <= How can I use the above declared dependency here and in my projects?
        }
    }
}
```

But my gradle complains that it cannot load the Flyway class.

Comment: Just checking that you're doing this for educational purposes vs developing a real Flyway Gradle plugin which already exists: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flyway class is in the `org.flywaydb.core` package. You missed the `core` bit. My full code that works:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway; // << can import here

buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.1.2"
    }

}
apply plugin: DatabaseHandlerPlugin

class DatabaseHandlerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('databaseHandler') {
            doLast {
                Flyway f = new Flyway()
                println "Flyway: $f"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
> gradle databaseHandler    
:databaseHandler
Flyway: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway@7b27e8f4
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but unfortunately even then it isn't working, same problem as before: the class cannot be found inside the plugin task.

Comment: @CryNickSystems is your class right there in the `build.gradle` file? How is your code structured?

Comment: No, it is not. It is coming from the dependency ("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.1.2")

Comment: @CryNickSystems no I mean your class `DatabaseHandlerPlugin`.

Comment: I am adding it in other subprojects / submodules like this: 'apply from 'plugins/databaseHandler.gradle'